# How can I solve this Differential Equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please help me solve this equation. I have tried many times but unable to solve it.
$$e^y \left(\frac{dy}{dx} + 1\right) = e^x$$

Comment: **Hint:** Try multiplying both sides by $e^x$ and then putting it in a form to test for an Exact Equation and then solving.

Comment: Many times... great... let's put all that hard work to use by *putting the forward motion  into the question statement* so we can help you find your way.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner shouldn't that be $y(x)=x - ln(2)$?

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

If we put $$z=y+x $$

the equation  becomes

$$z'e^z=e^{2x} $$

which gives
$$e^z=\frac{1}{2}e^{2x}+C $$

and

$$y=z-x=\ln(\frac{1}{2}e^{2x}+C)-x $$